# Finding Unique Airline Routes with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, join, max, common-table-expression, min

I have two tables:

```
AirPorts (IATA_CODE TEXT, LATITUDE REAL, LONGITUDE REAL)
AirRoutes (ROUTE_FROM TEXT, ROUTE_TO TEXT)
```

The AirRoutes table includes routes from Airports that are not listed in the Airports table. It also includes multiple occurrences of the same route.

First of all, I wish to select all unique Routes that start and end at airports that exist in the 'AirPorts' table. I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it seems to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AirRoutes.ROUTE_FROM, AirRoutes.ROUTE_TO FROM AirRoutes
WHERE EXISTS 
   (SELECT IATA_CODE
    FROM AirPorts_SM
    WHERE AirRoutes.ROUTE_FROM = IATA_CODE)
AND EXISTS
   (SELECT IATA_CODE
    FROM AirPorts_SM
    WHERE AirRoutes.ROUTE_TO = IATA_CODE);
```

Next, I would like to filter out B-A routes where A-B routes are returned, so if there is a route AMS to DUB, I don't want to return DUB to AMS as well.

How would you do that?

Finally, and I don't know if this is possible, I would like to get the positions included, so each row would be like:

```
ROUTE_FROM=AMS, LAT_FROM=52.3, LON_FROM=4.76, ROUTE_TO=DUB, LAT_TO=53.42, LON_TO=-6.24
```

How would you do that? Perhaps this is too adventurous for one query, and I should break it into three parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE to get all the distinct pairs of `ROUTE_FROM` and `ROUTE_TO` of `AirRoutes` and  join it to 2 copies of `AirPorts` like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
         MIN(ROUTE_FROM, ROUTE_TO) ROUTE_FROM,
         MAX(ROUTE_FROM, ROUTE_TO) ROUTE_TO
  FROM AirRoutes
)  
SELECT c.ROUTE_FROM, f.LATITUDE LAT_FROM, f.LONGITUDE LON_FROM,
       c.ROUTE_TO, t.LATITUDE LAT_TO, t.LONGITUDE LON_TO
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN AirPorts f ON f.IATA_CODE = c.ROUTE_FROM
INNER JOIN AirPorts t ON t.IATA_CODE = c.ROUTE_TO;
```

Comment: Very impressive. Please can you explain what this is actually doing:

    MIN(ROUTE_FROM, ROUTE_TO) ROUTE_FROM

Comment: @TimMakins for every pair of (ROUTE_FROM, ROUTE_TO), it returns the min value (by performing a string comparison) while MAX() returns the max value. This way if you have in different rows ('a', 'b') and ('b', 'a') the result is ('a', 'b') in both rows and then DISTINCT keeps only 1 of them.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I don't understand why there is the Min expression, then a space, then ROUTE_FROM, before the comma and then the Max part. Its the fact that there are 2 items, then a comma, then 2 items before the FROM that I don't understand.

Comment: @TimMakins MIN() is a scalar function and in this case it takes 2 arguments ROUTE_FROM and ROUTE_TO to compare them and return the min of the 2. The result of this comparison is aliased to ROUTE_FROM. It could also be written: `MIN(ROUTE_FROM, ROUTE_TO) AS ROUTE_FROM` but `AS` is optional and I rarely use it.

Comment: Now I understand. It was the fact that the alias was using an existing name that totally confused me.